# pyodbc connection error when trying to connect to DB on localhost

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a local DB on my machine called 'Test' which contains a table called 'Tags'. I am able to access this DB and query from this table through SQL Server management studio 2008.

However, when using pyodbc I keep running into problems.

Using this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost:1433;DATABASE=Test')
```

yields the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. (14) (SQLDriverConnectW); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()). (14)')
```

(with or without specifying the port)

Trying an alternative connection string:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost\Test,1433')
```

yields no error, but then:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Tags")
```

yields the error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Tags'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Why could this be?

Comment: What other combinations have you tried?

Comment: Well, I copied this DB from an external server, and when I tried to connect to that server, this connection string (without port specification) worked. i.e., "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DB-TEST-SRV;DATABASE=Test" yielded no error, and querying in the way I specified above yielded the expected result with no error.

Answer (score 6):

I tried changing your query to

```
SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Tags
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any authentication attributes in your connection strings. Try this (I'm using Windows authentication):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',
                      server = 'localhost', database = 'Test')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# assuming that Tags table is in dbo schema
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.Tags")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing 'localhost' with either '(local)' or '.'. This solution fixed the problem for me.

Comment: for me "." worked, but 'localhost' or 'local' didn't.

Answer (score 1):

For me, apart from maintaining the connection details (user, server, driver, correct table name etc.),

I took these steps:

1. Checked the ODBC version here (Windows 10) ->
2. (search for) ODBC ->
3. Select 32/64 bit version ->
4. Drivers ->
5. Verify that the ODBC driver version is present there. If it is not, use this link to download the relevant driver: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Reference Link: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn170514(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost:1433;DATABASE=Test')

This connection lack of instance name and the port shouldn't be writen like this.

my connection is this:

```
cn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;PORT=1433;DATABASE=ybdb;UID=sa;PWD=*****')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Ujp.png)